# pg_dump in Process not writing any file

Tags: c#, process, postgresql-9.3

I am writing some c# code to take a backup of my Posgresql database.

```
public static bool MakeBackup(string schema, string userName, string password, string backupFolder)
{
    var database = "Import";
    var timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd-HH-mm-ss");
    var file = String.Format("{0}_{1}.sql", schema, timestamp);
    var fullPath = String.Format(@"{0}\{1}", backupFolder, file);

    var executablePath = @"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin\pg_dump.exe";

    var arguments = String.Format(@" -h localhost -d{0} -n{1} -U{2} -w{3} > {4}",database, schema, userName, password, fullPath );

    Boolean result = false;
    try
    {
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo info = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        info.FileName = executablePath;
        info.Arguments = arguments;
        info.CreateNoWindow = true;
        info.UseShellExecute = false;
        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.StartInfo = info;
        proc.Start();
        proc.WaitForExit();
        result = true;

   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
        //Console.writeline(ex.Message);
   }
   return result;
}
```

I started out by getting an access denied error. This I fixed by making sure my application has writing access to the output folder and setting the `info.Arguments` to the full pg_dump.exe path.

I tried pause in debug, then copy the arguments and execute them in a command prompt this works fine.

So I don´t get any error but my folder remains empty.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to forward the output of pg_dump with > to a file. This will not work, since there is no shell handling the output forwarding. Rather you should use pg_dump's option `-f output_file` to save the output to a desired file.

At the moment the `> file` will just be sent as a command line argument to pg_dump and it might or might not show error for it.